# How do I filter HTTPS URLs in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, https

Most pages on our website use `http://` - but some pages use `https://`

I want to filter out of Google Analytics anything starting with `https://` as it's not relevant to our analytics, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Create a filter on Google Analytics that will exclude this traffic:
[image]

The regex is:

```
https:\/\/.*
```

However, it's always a best practice to keep the raw data (that is, in your case, both http and https) intact, and to apply the new filter on a new **View**.