# How Can I Use Google Analytics to Compare HTTP and HTTPS PageViews of the Same Page?

Tags: google-analytics

My site serves pages as both HTTP and HTTPS (no forwarding from HTTP to HTTPS, both return 200s). I have GA tracking on the pages and I see traffic generated from both HTTP and HTTPS page loads. Is there a filter/report I can run in GA to show for a particular page what proportion of pageviews were HTTP vs HTTPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be a way to do this built into Google Analytics.   Google Analytics doesn't have "protocol" or even "request URI" as a dimension that could be used to create an advanced segment.

One option would be to create views with filters for each of HTTP and HTTPS.  We have a question here about how to do that: [How do I filter HTTPS URLs in Google Analytics?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/69075/how-do-i-filter-https-urls-in-google-analytics)  You would then have to switch views to see stats about some page.

Another way to do it would be to create a custom dimension.  You would need to alter your GA snippet to add code like:

```
ga('set', 'dimension1', location.protocol);
```

You could then create an advanced segment based on this dimension1.